# Spring boot - Adding data read only

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

I am thinking what would be best solution for following case. Suppose we have at start CRUD app - using Spring Boot. I would like to add read only state for this application - which allows only data read and blocks create, update, delete data operations for admin role. I think about adding aspect (@Aspect) which checks current app state (which is saved in db) and starts if create, update, update operations are invoked. If app is in read-only state - exception will be thrown (handled by @ControllerAdvice)

I wonder if adding aspect is the best option - I dont want modify existing code. Whats your take on that? Moreover - how would you write integration tests for @aspect - testing if aspect starts properly? How could be aspects tested for this case? What are good practises for testing @aspects (integration tests @springboottest)

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to modify the existing code?

Answer (score 3):

This honestly seems like an inconvenient way of doing this. Why not just add an Interceptor that checks for this? I did something similar before

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReadOnlyModeInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final ServerProperties serverProperties;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        if (serverProperties.isReadOnlyMode()) {
            String method = request.getMethod();
            boolean isReadOnlyMethod = "GET".equals(method) || "OPTIONS".equals(method);
            String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
            boolean isReadOnlyPath = isReadOnlyPath(servletPath);
            if (!isReadOnlyMethod && isReadOnlyPath) {
                throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Server is in read-only mode.");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean isReadOnlyPath(String servletPath) {
        if (serverProperties.isFullyReadOnly()) {
            return true;    // wildcard option, entire server is read-only
        }
        return serverProperties.getReadOnlyPaths().stream().anyMatch(servletPath::contains);
    }

}
```

You also need to register it

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ReadOnlyModeInterceptor readOnlyModeInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(readOnlyModeInterceptor).order(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe also include `HEAD` HTTP method as readonly for completeness

Comment: @rkosegi Yeah we'd never get those, but if those are expected that's a good add

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek thanks. For this case - intercepter would be tested like normal controller or service? How would you write integration tests for interceptor?

Comment: @Sunderi The interceptor is always triggered. You just write your test as normal integration tests, while setting the read-only flag.

Comment: is it possible to disable Create, Update, Delete operations on controller using interceptor? After setting readonly mode I'd like to return some kind of response for those 3 operations leaving Read - this should work no matter of read state

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek is it possible to set when interceptor starts like in aspects?

Comment: @Sunderi you were talking about `@ControllerAdvice` before making me think you already knew how. You can just handle the exception you throw in a class with `@ControllerAdvice` and return something custom there. Also, you don't need to set if it starts or not. Whether it does anything is handled by the Boolean flag. But of course you COULD conditionally register this interceptor depending on that flag.